# Intellij not detecting the latest dependency

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am running a test file using `mvn test -Dtest=MessageListenerAppTest`, and it's running fine.
But when I open the MessageListenerAppTest.java file and right-click on it in Intellij.
I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ScriptEvaluationException`

I tried restarting Intellij, invalidating caches, but still the same error.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Check if this helps: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-noclassdeffounderror or https://techythought.wordpress.com/2020/06/29/junit5-error-via-intellij-idea-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-junit-platform-launcher-testexecutionlistener/

Comment: @pringi I already had junit-jupiter-api. I included `junit-jupiter-enginer` in the pom.xml after reading the above article. It's working now. That's weird because the maven command `mvn test -Dtest=MessageListenerAppTest` works with only `junit-jupiter-api` dependency. What could be the reason for this?